# Are these Equivalent Functions?

Tags: functions, logarithms

Let $$f(x)= \frac{1}{2 \log(x) + 1}$$ and $$g(x)= \frac{1}{\log(x^2) + 1}$$ The question asked was if these two functions were equivalent, and using log properties I see them as equivalent, however, the solution says they are not. Could anyone explain why this is the case?

Thanks!

Comment: $f$ is only defined for $x>0$, while $g$ is defined for any $x\neq 0$. Equivalence of functions requires them to have the same domain of definition.

Comment: The domain of the functions should be specified to verify the statement.

Comment: @rahul "equivalent" in which sense ? Do you mean "equal" ?

Comment: @Zuy $f$ is also not defined for $x=e^{-1/2}$, but nevertheless the comment hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Note: $\log(x^2)=2\log|x|$ for real $x\ne 0$.

Comment: @bjorn93 that is a good point and not something I have realised before.